# Is it true that $\gcd(\left|a\right|,\left|b\right|) \leq \min(\left|a\right|,\left|b\right|)$, if $ab \neq 0$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, gcd-and-lcm

I tried to search for duplicate questions but I did not find any.

So here is my initial question:

> Is it true that $\gcd(\left|a\right|,\left|b\right|) \leq \min(\left|a\right|,\left|b\right|),$
> if $ab \neq 0$?

**MY ATTEMPT**

Since $\gcd(a,b)$ is the *greatest common divisor* of $a$ and $b$, in particular, it *is* a common divisor of $a$ and $b$.  Thus we have both
$$\gcd(a,b) \mid a \implies \gcd(a,b) \leq \left|a\right|$$
and
$$\gcd(a,b) \mid b \implies \gcd(a,b) \leq \left|b\right|,$$
where the conclusions $\gcd(a,b) \leq \left|a\right|$ and $\gcd(a,b) \leq \left|b\right|$ are justified by $ab \neq 0$.
Thus, we obtain
$$\gcd(a,b) = \gcd(\left|a\right|,\left|b\right|) \leq \min(\left|a\right|,\left|b\right|).$$

Here is my final question:

> Is this proof correct?  If not, how can it be mended so as to produce a valid argument?

Comment: $\gcd(0,1)=1>0=\min\{0,1\}$

Comment: Right, perhaps I should have just specified that all variables are positive.  Thank you for your comment, @jjagmath!

Comment: Now that you specified that $ab\ne 0$ you should ask yourself "where in my proof I used that hypothesis?". If you never used that hypothesis, the proof can't be right since it will also apply to the previous counterexample.

Comment: Yes, of course!  Hold on, @jjagmath.

Comment: There?  Is it better now, @jjagmath?

Comment: Yes, the important point is that $x\mid y$ implies $|x| \le |y|$ only if $y\ne 0$. Now you proof is complete.

Comment: Thank you for the confirmation, @jjagmath!  If you could write out your last comment as an actual answer, I will be more than happy to upvote and then accept it.  =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $x$ and $y$ integers, the implication $x\mid y \implies |x|\le |y|$ is only valid for $y\ne 0$.